# Data on forest cover (land use) in The Gambia from 2010 or more recent

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment, africa

I am looking for a data set on **forest cover in The Gambia** that meets the following conditions:

- a high enough resolution (e.g. 30x30m)
- a data set (i.e. classified satellite imagery data) on forest cover in The Gambia post-2010 and pre-2008.

I am looking to analyse the effect of a development project implemented between 2008 and 2010 in The Gambia. In order to control for differences in initial forest cover, I would like to find two data sets (from the indicated time periods) that follow the same classification scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [global Forest Change](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest) cover From Hansen et al. They used Landsat 7 images from 2000 to 2013 to assess forest cover changes. Tiles can be [downloaded from their website](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.1.html) under creative common license.

Answer (score 1):

The FAO Global Forest Resources Assessment does not have map data, but does have a lot of aggregated data and trends on forests for each country in the world. The assessment and report is updated every 5 years: 2015, 2010, 2005, 2000, 1995, 1990, ...

http://www.fao.org/forestry/fra/en/